# LIBGDX depth buffer doing nothing

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I'm trying to get my depth buffer working for a 3D game engine written with LIBGDX, so that I don't have to sort my objects by their Z every frame. I believe I'm missing a critical step in setting the depth of my shapes. In my render function, I have this code:

> ```
> Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
> Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LESS);
> Gdx.gl.glDepthRangef(0, 2000);
> Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
> ```

And in my draw function for all of my different shapes I'm using setColor like this:

> ```
> GDX.renderer.setColor(r, g, b, depth);
> ```

My efforts are having no effect on the order that anything is rendered. Am I setting the depth wrong? Is there more setup I need to do?

Comment: `glDepthMask(true)`. Also, I'm not sure what `renderer` is, but it's error prone to reference OpenGL objects statically. If you are using ModelBatch, these calls may not work because ModelBatch manages GL state for you. You should instead be using attributes in your Shader implementation to set this up.

Comment: Please carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and adjust your question accordingly. Also, depth is not a color.